# How to scrape project details from the world bank website using google collab?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I am trying to scrape all the details of the project from the website https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/projects-list?os=0

I am new to web scrapping and trying to use beautiful soup in google collab

Problem faced by me is:

1. I am getting WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1 while installing selenium in colab

```
    !pip install selenium
    !apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
    !apt install chromium-chromedriver
    !cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
    from selenium import webdriver
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

2. I am not able to fetch the table details while using beautiful soup. I am using the following code

```
titleList = bsobj.findAll('td', {'class':'ng-tns-c1-0'})
titleList
```

Is there any easier way to fetch the project details in the table while using colab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the behaviour of the website in your browser, it needs some `time` to render the table, so you simply have to wait.

**Option#1**

Simply use [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to wait:

```
...
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
...
```

**Option#2**

Use [`selenium waits`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)(recommended) to solve the issue:

```
...
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'YOUR SELECTOR')))
...
```

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

---

**Alternative** - Get data directly as JSON via api:

```
import requests
url = 'https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/projects?format=json&rows=100'
d = requests.get(url).json()['projects']
```

Output:

```
{'P178559': {'curr_total_commitment': '0',
  'curr_ibrd_commitment': '0',
  'curr_ida_commitment': '0',
  'id': 'P178559',
  'regionname': 'East Asia and Pacific',
  'countryname': ['Republic of Indonesia'],
  'prodline': 'RE',
  'lendinginstr': 'Program-for-Results Financing',
  'lendinginstrtype': 'PR',
  'supplementprojectflg': 'Y',
  'projectstatusdisplay': 'Active',
  'project_name': 'INEY IPF Additional Financing',
  'board_approval_month': 'March',
  'totalamt': '0',
  'borrower': 'Republic of Indonesia',
  'impagency': 'Ministry of Home Affairs, National Statistical Agency, Ministry of Villages, Disadvantaged Areas and Transmigration, Ministry of Education and Culture, National Development Planning Agency, Ministry of Health, Ministry of Social Affairs, BKKBN, The National Population and Family Planning Board, Coordinating Ministry for Human Development and Cultural Affairs, Ministry of Finance, Secretariat of the Vice President',
  'countrycode': ['ID'],
  'countryshortname': 'Indonesia',
  'p2a_updated_date': '2023-03-14 00:00:00.0',
  'sector1': {'Name': '', 'Percent': 0},
  'theme1': '!$!0',
  'totalcommamt': '6,000,000',
  'approvalfy': '2023',
  'source': ['IBRD'],
  'mjthemecode': '2',
   ...
```